# Right way of using Azure Mobile services with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

What is the most optimum way of using azure mobile services with Xamarin Forms app? I'm using the Managed Backend version of the azure mobile services.

This is my project architecture so far:

App(portable)

App.Droid

App.iOS

App.WinPhone

Apart from this I've added 2 more projects to the solution

App.Service

is the azure mobile service, this is not directly used in any of the projects above but via Table Controllers (Web API stuff)

App.Shared (PCL)

This has all my model classes & a wrapper on top of the azure APIs. The idea was to use this PCL as a reusable lib that I could use on any other clients on a future day.

All azure related bits are only in app.Shared & native projects.

This setup works well with Windows Phone Emulator & running the Azure services locally.

However, I can't access the Azure Services (running locally) using Android device or emulator. It always immediately returns with an "Unauthorized" error.

I can access the service running locally from the browser app running in droid simulator. I can also access this service from the Chrome app running on my device.

Any thing you see I've wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you're tables being protected by the application key? Is there a chance that the Android version isn't getting this key passed in somehow?

Comment: no they are not. I am trying to access the backend running on my machine locally, not deployed on Azure. When Deployed on azure they all work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this - basically you need to write the common access code in your Xamarin Forms PCL, but instantiate and register the Azure client in the actual platform project.  It is much easier with a full dependency injection framework, like Autofac, as opposed to just the Xamarin service locator.

Most of the logic will be in a class in the PCL.  It should take in a dependency of the MobileServiceSyncClient (sorry if that name is off, not by my code), which is the actual client you'll call GetTable, Update, etc on.

You then construct a few things in your iOS or Android project - the MobileSyncStore, which depends on SQLite, as well as the client (which cannot init in a PCL).  Give that to your logic class, then register the logic class (in my code, this is AzureStorageService, implementing IMobileServiceClient).  Now any class needing to talk to the server simply gets a dependency to IMobileServiceClient, and is good to go.

Comment: Well yes, this is one way of doing it. problem with this approach is, I do not get a 100% self sufficient API wrapper PCL library, that has all the business logic. That's the idea I am trying to achieve here. 
If I have to write Dependency Injection, then I am banking on individual platforms to do something for me. 
Seems like once the backend is deployed on Azure, everything works fine. Only when running it locally seems to have issues when accessing the backend from client apps.

Comment: XF does have items which require platform specific code - however the DI allows you to separate the business logic (which stays in the PCL) from the platform specific init.  In my current app, the platform specific code is all of 5 lines (init, construct, and setup local storage).